# Default value of uninitialized struct members

Tags: vb.net, data-structures

Is there a default value of an uninitialized member of a `Structure` in VB.NET?

Probably a basic question but my Google foo only led me to instances of people trying to *set* the default value of a structure member.

Basically I would like to know if it is sufficient to do (in this case, in a module)

```
Private Structure FooStructure
    Public Bar As Decimal
    Public Buzz As Byte()
End Structure

Private Foo As FooStructure = New FooStructure
```

Or if it is required to properly properly initialize to guarantee the state of the members:

```
Private Foo As FooStructure = New FooStructure With {.Bar = 0, .Buzz = {0, 0}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB.net, the default values for Decimals and Bytes are both 0, therefore, when you run `Private Foo As FooStructure = New FooStructure` the system assigns the value `0` for Bar and Buzz. This should be sufficient and equal to your second example.

Comment: Thanks, following your tack of checking the docs for each type I realised structures are value types so I shouldn't even need the `= New FooStructure` I think. :)

Comment: `Buzz` is an array of bytes, and arrays are reference types, so `Buzz` will be initialized to `Nothing` / null.

Comment: @Mark, ah the proverbial ointment fly! Thanks (Getting to the point that I'm considering converting these items to a class anyway)